# Slide up down effect in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iOS app i've to design screen like attached image.[image]

when i click on '-' or '+' button in Explanation section it show/hide Explanation section.

by default all explanation sections will be hidden(as shown in bottom of image), if i click '+' button it will expand the view and button become '-' and vice versa.
I didn't find ant useful on google(may be i'm searching by wring keywords!)
Any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can i go for insert/delete row approach in tableview?

Comment: Look at `UIScrollView` you can just amend the contentSize of the scroll view when you expand or hide or like Blios has said use insert delete in `UITableView`

Comment: Create a `UITableView` with a custom cell corresponding to an array of model objects (assuming there are more options besides just the three given on screen). Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the `+ Explanation` view. Show/Hide full explanation based on taps on `+ Explanation` view and preserve said state in a boolean.... That's the approach I'd take. Good luck.

Comment: @Popeye, I **strongly** disagree with using a `UIScrollView`. The implementation will be more of a pain and memory cost will be higher than using `UITableView`, which has the advantage of cell reuse.

Comment: That screenshot looks like a web app...

Comment: @JRG-Developer I agree. I don't know what I was thinking, definitely use `UITableView` over the `UIScrollView` idea. But I will still leave my comment as it does add an alternative and whilst it maybe a pain and memory consuming it would still work. But yes totally agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` (that change height, etc.), others would be [inserting/deleting rows](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController) or using expandable sections like [in apples sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html).

I would personally go with option 1 and use some UIGestureRecognizer

edit: just like [JRG-Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1648724/jrg-developer) commented on your question now !

Comment: +1: Yep, this is the way to go. `GCRetractableSectionController` looks neat, too! Thanks for sharing link to it. :D

Comment: not exactly for this case, but you could take a look at this nested tableView project to get an overview https://github.com/serverdensity/ios-SDNestedTable

Comment: Thanks @blub i would like to go for your suggestion.