# ExpandableTableView: Only 1 row can be expanded at any one time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using ExpandableTableView.
Here's [a link](https://github.com/wannabegeek/ExpandableTableView)!

1. Only 1 row can be expanded at any one time while other should collapsed.
2. When a row is expanded, any tap on the screen will collapse the expanded row.

How can i get that?

Comment: you can [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085625/slide-up-down-effect-in-ios) for help

Answer (score 0):

**In `ExpandableTableView.h`**

Take previous section variable

```
NSInteger presection;
```

**In ExpandableTableView.m**

in `- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` Method set presection intial Value

```
presection=-1;
```

Replace `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // either expand the section or call the  delegates method if already expanded


    if ([_expandedSectionIndexes containsIndex:indexPath.section]) {
        // we're already expanded
        [self contractSection:presection]; // Contrace Previos Section

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // close the section
            [self contractSection:indexPath.section];
            [super deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        } else {
            if ([_expandableDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
                [_expandableDelegate tableView:self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row - 1 inSection:indexPath.section]];
            }
        }
    } else if (indexPath.row == 0 && _ungroupSingleElement && [_expandableDataSource tableView:self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section] == 1) {
        if ([_expandableDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {
            [_expandableDelegate tableView:self didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
    } else {
        if (presection!=-1) {
            [self contractSection:presection];
        }
        presection=indexPath.section;
        [self expandSection:indexPath.section];
        [super deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
}
```